# How to set notification with custom sound in android 8.0?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-8.0-oreo

I have tried to set the custom notification sound it works fine below Oreo(8.0) devices but in Oreo device it doesn't trigger custom sound always trigger the default sound only. Can anyone help?

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Notification.Builder notificationBuilder =
                    new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle(title)
                            .setContentText(content)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            //.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX) // this is deprecated in API 26 but you can still use for below 26. check below update for 26 API
                            //.setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            // Configure the notification channel.
            AudioAttributes att = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                    .build();
            notificationChannel.setSound(defaultSoundUri, att);
            notificationChannel.setDescription(content);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());

        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle(title)
                            .setContentText(content)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX) // this is deprecated in API 26 but you can still use for below 26. check below update for 26 API
                            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were using an Android version that is under Oreo, you only have to add your MY_SOUND_NOTIFICATION.mp3 to your **Resources** in a folder named **raw** and start coding your class but since you are using Oreo or higher, you need to check your SDK_VERSION in order to use a method called `setSound` of the `NotificationChannel`

I wont post any code since I you didnt poste code to correct. If you post some code, I will be pleased to help you

Comment: i'm  check condition sdk version oreo using notication channel but i'm also get default notification sound.